# How to declare variable in paypal.paypent.create and use it outside

Tags: javascript, node.js, paypal

Hi I'm working on paypal function  I've promblem that I declare variable in var but I can't use it outside function

```
async openOrder({request, response }) {



 const paypalResponse = await paypal.payment.create(create_payment_json, function(error, payment) {
    if (error) {
        throw error;
    } else {
        console.log(payment);
        for (let i = 0; i < payment.links.length; i++) {
            console.log(payment.links.length);
            if (payment.links[i].rel === 'approval_url') {
               // I declare varialbe here
                var paymentLink = payment.links[i].href;
                // response.redirect('payment.links[i].href');
            }
        }
    }
});
 console.log(paymentLink) // return undefined
}
```

the reason that I can't use response.redirect because I'm working on backend that return only json api [ run different port with frontend ]
so I want to return Link url paypal in json .

How can I declare my variable payment link in async function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay you misunderstood the asynchronous nature of javascript. The `console.log` will execute even before the payment is complete. Whatever you need to do with the result is supposed to be given in the callback.

So redirecting the user to a link is done inside the callback method. I have added the `return` statement, so that no multiple http response will be sent.

```
async openOrder({
    request,
    response
}) {

    const payment = await paypal.payment.create(create_payment_jsonfunction(error, payment) {
        if (error) {
            throw error;
        } else {
            console.log(payment);
            // do you operations with result here
            for (let i = 0; i < payment.links.length; i++) {
                console.log(payment.links.length);
                if (payment.links[i].rel === 'approval_url') {
                    // I declare varialbe here
                    var paymentLink = payment.links[i].href;

                    return response.redirect('payment.links[i].href');
                }
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: I cant do something like this because in paypal-rest-sdk  It error cb is not a function

I think It required callback function